# Right-click on a query result row in SQL Server Management Studio and run macro

Tags: sql-server, ssms, smo

Is it possible to write a macro in SQL Server Management Studio that will be displayed in the context menu that comes up when right-clicking a row in the result set of a query?  This macro would take and process the contents (data) of that row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no, you can't do that without some serious SSMS internals hacking.
you can select all data in the grid and copy paste it.

Comment: Dear Mladen Prajdic, based on your background (MVP) and the tool you have written, I am going to accept your answer that it cannot be done.  Thank you.

Comment: thanx! however if you do find an easy way to do it plese don't hesitate to let us know.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need Excel and VBA functionality.
Why don't you export your data from SQL Server to Excel and write Visual Basic script to accomplish what you need?

Comment: What I need to accomplish is to use the data from a row to call other SQL scripts.

Comment: What kind of script do you need? Can it be done in pure T-SQL?

Comment: Pavel, what I was hoping to do was: 1) Choose a row from the result grid. 2) That row would contain a value which is a PK in some other table.  3) Look up that value in that table and display the result.  This would be much faster than going to the query pane and writing a query for it (select * from lookup_table where PK = 'the value in the result row').  BTW, is a T-SQL query different than a reqular SQL query?

Comment: Why don't you use something like:
SELECT original_table.ID, lookup_table.* FROM
lookup_table
INNER JOIN
original_table
ON
original_table.Reference_ID=lookup_table.ID

Comment: My problem is not in forming the query - rather, I am trying to find a faster and more convenient way to do a look up.  When you have a value in the grid, instead of copying/pasting that value back into the query pane, run the macro I was thinking of which in turn runs the SQL query for you.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what is actually required. Still thinking INNER JOIN will do for you. Feel free to submit this issue as a separate question.